# Export The $PATH Variable, Line-By-Line

Tags: code-golf, string

Inspired by [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600018/how-to-display-the-paths-in-path-separately) on AskUbuntu.

Your job is extremely simple. Take the PATH environment variable (`echo $PATH`) and export it such that each entry (separated by the `:` character) is on its own line.

For example, if the PATH is `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`, your program should output:

```
/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
```

Your program may not return a leading newline, but it may return a single trailing newline. You do not need to check if the PATH is right, or that the directory exists. Your program should take no input, meaning that your program is responsible for getting the PATH itself. You may safely assume that objects in the PATH do not contain `:` or newlines. However, spaces are fair game.

Reference implementations are present in the answers to the question above.

#### Rules

- This is (obviously) code-golf, so the shortest answer will win the prized green checkmark.
- The accepted answer will be tested to make sure it's actually legit.
- Both Windows and *nix entries are accepted.

  - However, if you don't explicitly specify Windows, I will try running it in Linux and fail. (If it's obvious (hi, Batch!), you don't need to specify explicitly.)
- Only have one solution per answer. If you have both a Windows and *nix version, I will count the shorter one.
- If two answers have the same length, I will give priority to the one with the higher vote total. If they have the same vote total, I will count the older one. If the time posted is the same, I will choose the one that executes faster. If they execute in the same amount of time, I don't know.

#### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=96334,OVERRIDE_USER=15422;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Ahh! It was hard to visit the AskUbuntu Question without giving some golfing tipps.

Comment: Some of the (shell) answers seem to assume that the path doesn't contain spaces. Should they be corrected?

Comment: @Dennis Typically, the path variable shouldn't have spaces, but as they can, they should be corrected. However, we can safely assume that paths themselves won't contain : or a newline.

Comment: Is a function acceptable?

Comment: @corvus_192 Unless the challenge *explicitly* says otherwise, functions are allowed.

Comment: Similar to http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?PATH

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Z shell (zsh), 13 bytes

```zsh
<<<${(F)path}
```

Uses the [`$path` parameter](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell), which is a special array parameter used by the shell that is [tied](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-typeset) to the `$PATH` parameter, and a [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) to join an array with newlines.

Comment: Apparently one *does* simply out-golf @Dennis... Huh.

Answer (score 14):

### Bash/Coreutils, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
tr : '
'<<<$PATH
```

Comment: `tr : '\n'<<<$PATH` should work as well

Comment: It does . . . editing right now

Comment: I think you can remove the spaces around `<<<` as well (tested on Ubuntu only)

Comment: @Arnauld i don't think that's Ubuntu only thing, it's bash thing, so should work accross the distros

Comment: The \n can be replaced by a newline reducing the bytes from 17 to 16.

Comment: @RomanCzyborra how so ?

Comment: i mutated your reply as i cannot force linebreaks in my comments it seems

Comment: It doesn't save any bytes, but using `\\n` instead of the quoted variable is more readable imho.

Answer (score 10):

### Batch, 41 bytes

```
@for %%a in ("%PATH:;=";"%")do @echo %%~a
```

`PATH` is semicolon-delimited on Windows of course. Conveniently, `for` splits on semicolons by default, but inconveniently, also on spaces, so I have to use string replace trickery to quote each path element before splitting. It then remains to remove the quotes afterwards.

Comment: Running from the command line you can replace `%%` with `%` saving 2 bytes.

Comment: @DavidPostill Wouldn't that make it a code snippet rather than a program?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact code golf rules are, but aren't most of other answers just snippets as well? Most of them require a "shell" of some description to run ...

Answer (score 10):

## Z shell (zsh), 15 bytes

```zsh
<<<${PATH//:/
}
```

You can test the code on [Anarchy Golf](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb): click *use form*, select *zsh*, paste the code and submit.

### Bash (pure), 19 bytes

```zsh
echo "${PATH//:/
}"
```

Same idea, but with Bash's less golfy syntax. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ri1lrX).

Answer (score 7):

## Powershell, 20 bytes

```
$env:PATH-split':'
```

Edit:

- ***-2** bytes off. Thanks to @TimmyD*

Old:

```
$env:PATH.split(":")
```

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 25 bytes

```
puts ENV["PATH"].split":"
```

Comment: Nice, tiny bit shorter than my answer on the original question on AskUbuntu

Comment: You don't need to count the Ruby invocation, only the program itself, so this is only 26 bytes.

Comment: @Jordan didn't know that. Is it in FAQ?

Comment: @Jordan It's shown in the tour itself. So, edited. Thank you for telling that

Comment: Oh, also you can change `split ":"` to `split":"` or `split ?:` for 1 byte.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 22 bytes

```
say$ENV{PATH}=~y/:/
/r
```

Needs `-E` or `-M5.010` to run :

```
perl -E 'say$ENV{PATH}=~y/:/
/r'
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Bash+Python, 43 bytes

Let's use shell's variable expansion. It eliminates calling `os.environ` , thus less code and less imports. That gives us 46 bytes, and with `xnor`'s trick and removing space before `-c` we've got 43 bytes.

```
python -c"print('$PATH'.replace(*':\n'))"
```

Comment: Note that this fails if a directory with a single quote or a backslash appears in your PATH.

Comment: @JoeyMarianer  Since there can be almost any character in filename/path string, then yes - this may fail and becase PATH will expand to '/dir'1:/dir2' , which gives incorrectly formatted command to python. The backslash doesn't necessarily fail - it just interprets what's in the string itself. IMHO , backslash escapes shouldn't appear in normal user's path names , so for 99% of cases this is OK. I however agree - this should be kept in mind anytime you deal with shell directly or indirectly as in this case

Answer (score 3):

### GNU `sed` + `bash`, 25 bytes:

```
sed 's/:/\n/g' <<<"$PATH"
```

If the `PATH` contains no directory name with whitespace, no quoting needed, 23 bytes:

```
sed 's/:/\n/g' <<<$PATH
```

Even shorter, transliterating `:` to newline, thanks to [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis):

```
sed y/:/\\n/<<<"$PATH"
```

Answer (score 3):

### Java, 58 bytes

```
System.out.print(System.getenv("Path").replace(';','\n'));
```

Full program: 106 bytes

```
class E {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.print(System.getenv("Path").replace(';', '\n'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 19 bytes

`"=$PATH<CR>p:s/:/\r/g<CR>`

Grab `$PATH` from the expression register and paste it. Turn the `:`s into newlines. Nothing tricky.

Comment: They should put this in Vim tutorials. As someone reading about how to get into Vim I appreciate this example.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <s>36</s> <s>35</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

*Saved 1 byte, thanks to Blackhole*
*Saved 2 bytes, thanks to user59178*
*saved 1 byte, thanks to Martijn*

#### *nix version

```
<?=strtr(getenv(PATH),":","
")?>
```

#### Windows version

```
<?=strtr(getenv(PATH),";","
")?>
```

Comment: To what does the star reffer?

Comment: @RomanGräf `*nix` is just a way of referring to a [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) system.

Comment: If you want a "multi-plataform" version, you can use the constant [`PATH_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)

Comment: Don't use `\n`, but a true newline instead, it'll save you one byte.

Comment: you can also drop the `"`s around `PATH`. You get an "use of undefined constant" notice but it still works, saving you 2 bytes.

Comment: Using the short echo `<?=strtr(getenv(PATH),":","")?>` safes a byte (*cant newline in comments)

Comment: `;` instead of `?>` saves one byte

Comment: deprecated, but still working: `$_ENV[PATH]` is one byte shorter than `getenv(PATH)`. With `register_globals=On` (PHP <4.2) you can even use `$PATH` to save another 6 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 49 bytes

Saving 2 bytes thanks to @xnor and 1 byte by replacing `environ` with `getenv` thanks to @Serg and @Oliver

```python
import os
print os.getenv('PATH').replace(*':\n')
```

For Python 3, just add `(` and `)` around the `print` argument and add 1 to the byte count.

Comment: How will this get the input?

Comment: @Anwar from os.environ['PATH'] , that will return the string

Comment: @Serg ah. got it.

Comment: `os.getenv` is shorter than `os.environ` by one byte

Comment: `replace` can take packed arguments `replace(*':\n')`.

Comment: You should mark that as Python 2, since it doesn't work in 3 if i recall correctly.

Comment: @DenkerAffe despite the `print()` syntax in 3, it also works.

Comment: @KarlNapf Yea, thats the point. This program as-is does not run in Python 3, so you should specify the version it works with.

Comment: @KarlNapf Replace `os.environ['PATH']` with `os.getenv('PATH')` to save one byte.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>85</s> 84 bytes

-1 byte for using `#import`

```c
#import<stdlib.h>
main(){char*a=getenv("PATH");while(*a)putchar(*a++==58?10:a[-1]);}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C (x86), 60 bytes

```c
f(){char*p=getenv("PATH");for(;*p;p++)putchar(*p-58?*p:10);}
```

This won't work on 64-bit platforms without including *stdlib.h*, since *getenv* returns an *int* (32 bits) while *char* pointers are 64 bits wide.

I have yet to find an online 32-bit C compiler.

## C (x86-64), 70 bytes

```c
f(){char*getenv(),*p=getenv("PATH");for(;*p;p++)putchar(*p-58?*p:10);}
```

Instead of including *stdlib.h*, we declare *getenv* ourselves as a function returning a *char* pointer.

I've tested this with gcc and clang on Linux; other setups may cry blood. Try it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/SNfiiv).

Answer (score 2):

## jq, 18 characters

(16 characters code + 2 characters command line option)

```
env.PATH/":"|.[]
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

bash-4.3$ jq -nr 'env.PATH/":"|.[]'
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 64 bytes

```
x=>Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Replace(";","\n");
```

Anonymous function which returns the path variable, each directory on a separate line. Note that `x` is just a dummy object to save 1 byte instead of using `()`.

Full program:

```
using System;

namespace ExportPathVariable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<object,string>f= x=>Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Replace(";","\n");

            Console.WriteLine(f(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Also works on UNIX systems if you replace `;` with `:`, presuming Mono libraries are available. **Try it online on [ideone](http://ideone.com/SW2O31), .NET Fiddle returns a security exception.**

Alternatively, a full C# program, which is rather verbose:

---

## C#, 118 bytes

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){Console.Write(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Replace(";","\n"));}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 39 bytes

Using sed command of @heemayl :

```
(system "sed 's/:/\\n/g' <<<\"$PATH\"")
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f)
  (system "sed 's/:/\\n/g' <<<\"$PATH\"")
)
```

Testing:
    (f)

Output:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/lib/java/bin
/usr/lib/java/jre/bin
#t
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 31 bytes

```
sys env "PATH"replace(':','\n')
```

In scala, `a b c` is syntactic sugar for `a.b(c)`, so this compiles to `sys.env("PATH").replace(':','\n')`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>28 25</s>  24 bytes

```perl6
%*ENV<PATH>.split(':')».put
```

```perl6
put %*ENV<PATH>~~tr/:/\n/
```

```perl6
put %*ENV<PATH>~~tr/:/
/
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 28 bytes

for unix-likes. I dunno how to do it on Windows since I'm not at a Windows box.

```
"PATH"getenv ":" "\n"replace
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 72 bytes

```
import System.Environment
m ':'='\n'
m x=x 
map m<$>getEnv"PATH">>=putStr
```

An expensive import and no `replace` within the standard library make it quite long.

Comment: surely `m ':'...` doesn't need that space?

Comment: @cat: the space is mandatory, because `'` is a valid character within identifiers. Without space we'd define a function named `m'`.

Answer (score 1):

## Awk, <s>51</s> 44 characters

```awk
BEGIN{$0=ENVIRON["PATH"];gsub(":",RS);print}
```

Thanks to:

- [ninjalj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/267/ninjalj) for suggesting to use `gsub()` instead of manipulating built-in variables (-7 characters)

The typical `awk` way would be to set up the built-in variables which influences how `awk` manipulates the data automatically:

```awk
BEGIN{FS=":";OFS=RS;$0=ENVIRON["PATH"];$1=$1;print}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

bash-4.3$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":";OFS=RS;$0=ENVIRON["PATH"];$1=$1;print}'
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
```

Comment: Doh. You are right, @ninjalj. I was to focused on doing it in `awk`-specific way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Node.js, 36 bytes

```
_=>process.env.PATH.split`:`.join`
`
```

Pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 34 bytes

```
disp(strrep(getenv('PATH'),58,10))
```

Here is an [online demo](https://ideone.com/zjgtYx) in Octave with a slight modification since `strrep` in octave requires the second and third inputs to be `char` variables rather than numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 38 bytes

```
cat(gsub(":","\n",Sys.getenv('PATH')))
```

Grab the $PATH, replace `:` with newlines and prints to stdout. [You can try it online here.](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=VapdHjKl)

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 43 Bytes

```
System.env['PATH'].replaceAll(":","\n")​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 36 characters

```
\A=@subst{\\:=\\n;@getenv{PATH}}@end
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

bash-4.3$ gema '\A=@subst{\\:=\\n;@getenv{PATH}}@end'
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge-98 + EVAR fingerprint, 34 bytes

```
"RAVE"4("HTAP"Gv
:!k@:':-!'0*-, >
```

Loads the EVAR fingerprint (`"RAVE"4(`) to easily access environment variables, gets the PATH envvar (`"HTAP"G`), and for each character, exits the program if the character is "\0" (`:!k@`), substracts ASCII 48 "0" if the char is ASCII 58 ":" (`:':-!'0*-`), and outputs the character (`,`).

Answer (score 0):

## ELF/x86, 78 bytes

```
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 01 00 00 00  43 0f 00 00 43 5f eb 10  |.ELF....C...C_..|
00000010  02 00 03 00 0c 50 eb 10  0c 50 eb 10 04 00 00 00  |.....P...P......|
00000020  5f 5f b1 05 be 49 50 eb  10 3d 20 00 01 00 5f f3  |__...IP..= ..._.|
00000030  a6 75 ef 89 f9 80 3f 3a  75 03 80 2f 30 42 ae 75  |.u....?:u../0B.u|
00000040  f4 4a 04 04 cd 80 93 cd  80 50 41 54 48 3d        |.J.......PATH=|
0000004e
```

NASM source:

```
BITS 32                                         ;
ORG 0x10eb5000                                  ;
                                                ;   ELF HEADER    --   PROGRAM HEADER
; ELF HEADER                                    ; +-------------+
DB 0x7f,'E','L','F'                             ; | magic       |    +--------------------+
                                                ; |             |    |                    |
; PROGRAM HEADERS                               ; |             |    |                    |
DD 1                                            ; |*class   32b | -- | type: PT_LOAD      |
                                                ; |*data   none |    |                    |
                                                ; |*version   0 |    |                    |
                                                ; |*ABI    SysV |    |                    |
DD 0xf43        ; offset = vaddr & (PAGE_SIZE-1); |*ABI vers    | -- | offset             |
                                                ; |             |    |                    |
entry:  inc     ebx     ; STDOUT_FILENO         ; |*PADx7       | -- | vaddr = 0x10eb5f43 |
        pop     edi     ; discard argc          ; |             |    |                    |
        jmp     short skip                      ; |             |    |                    |
DW 2                                            ; | ET_EXEC     | -- |*paddr LO           |
DW 3                                            ; | EM_386      | -- |*paddr HI           |
DD 0x10eb500c                                   ; |*version     | -- | filesz             |
DD 0x10eb500c                                   ; | entry point | -- | memsz              |
DD 4                                            ; | ph offset   | -- | flags: RX          |
                                                ; |             |    |                    |
skip:   pop     edi     ; discard argv[0]       ; |*sh offset   | -- |*align              |
        pop     edi     ; discard argv[1]=NULL  ; |             |    |                    |
env:    mov     cl,5    ; \ strlen("PATH=")     ; |             |    |                    |
        mov     esi,PATH; > "PATH="             ; |*flags    /--|    |                    |
DB 0x3d         ; cmp eax,0x10020               ; |*ehsize      |    +--------------------+
DW 32                                           ; | phentsize   |
DW 1                                            ; | phnum       |
                                                ; |             |
        pop     edi     ; > envp                ; |*shentsize   |
        repe    cmpsb   ; > strcmp(envp,"PATH="); |*shnum       |
        jne     env     ; /                     ; |*shstrndx    |
        mov     ecx,edi                         ; +-------------+

nlcolon:cmp     byte[edi],58  ; \ if (char == ':')
        jne     nosub         ; >
        sub     byte[edi],48  ; >   char -= '0'
nosub:  inc     edx           ; > wlen++
        scasb                 ; >
        jne     nlcolon       ; / while(char != 0)

        dec     edx           ; wlen--
        add     al,4
        int     0x80          ; write(1, ecx, wlen)
        xchg    eax,ebx
        int     0x80          ; exit(...)

PATH: db "PATH="
```

Answer (score 0):

## DOS .COM File, 52 bytes

```
00000000  31 f6 8b 16 2c 00 8e da  bf 2f 01 b9 05 00 f3 a6  |1...,..../......|
00000010  74 06 f7 d9 f2 ae eb f0  b4 02 ac 3c 3b 75 06 b2  |t..........<;u..|
00000020  0d cd 21 b0 0a 92 08 c0  74 04 cd 21 eb ea c3 50  |..!.....t..!...P|
00000030  41 54 48 3d                                       |ATH=|
00000034
```

NASM Source:

```
BITS 16
ORG 0x100

                                ; we assume ax is zeroed on start                      
        xor     si,si
        mov     dx, [0x2c]
        mov     ds, dx          ; PSP:002C points to the environment segment

searchpath:
        mov     di, PATH
        mov     cx, 5
        repe    cmpsb           ; search for PATH= in environment
        je      loop            ; jump if found
        neg     cx
        repne   scasb           ; scan for '\0': skip to the next env var
        jmp     searchpath

loop:   mov     ah, 2           ; WRITE TO STDOUT; AH=02 DL=char
        lodsb                   ; load the next character from PATH
        cmp     al,59
        jne     nosemi
        mov     dl, 0x0d        ; \ if it is a semicolon,
        int     0x21            ; > output '\r',
        mov     al,0x0a         ; / and change it to '\n'
nosemi: xchg    dx,ax           ; 1 byte shorter than mov dl,al
        or      al,al
        je      end             ; if it is '\0', end
        int     0x21
        jmp     loop

end:    ret

PATH: db "PATH="
```

On some older DOS versions (e.g: 3.3) SI is apparently zeroed at start, so 2 bytes can be saved. Newer DOS versions apparently set SI to 100h.

Answer (score 0):

## Q 20 Characters

If no double quotes in the output the length is 17 chars

```
q)-1":"vs getenv`PATH;
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
q)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 34 bytes

```
puts [regsub -all : $env(PATH) \n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCG6KDW9uDRJQTcxJ0fBSkElNa9MI8AxxENTISYv9v9/AA)